# Newbie wondering about standard deviation and how to detect outliers in new datapoints

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, standard-error, anomaly-detection, range

So I have a dataset, with the count of records processed per day in each, e.g.

| 27th April: 3491 | 28th April: 2058 | 29th April: 9321 | 30th April: 1021

I want to be able to take a new day's count of data, and detect whether the count is within an acceptable range, or if it's anomalous, e.g. maybe we only processed 100 records that day, and that should trigger a notification. Or we double-processed the day's records and that's resulted in double what it should be, and that should trigger a notification.

I've been looking at standard deviation as a way of doing this, so finding a certain range of data around the mean where, if a new point falls in this range, it's acceptable.

Is this the correct way to go about this, or what other statistical method should I be using? I've found that with some of the datasets I've encountered, the range (i.e. mean - SD to mean to mean + SD) is quite wide and the minimum value is below zero, which I think is wrong.

Any advice would be appreciated, I know this is probably quite an easy problem for all of you, but I'm stumped!

Comment: You say you'd worry if a count doubles from one day to the next, but in your 4-day exmp the count goes from 2058 to 9321, and you don't comment. You'd worry if the count was only 100, but don't comment on going from 9321 to 1021, which seems a huge drop. So I'm confused: (1) Do you already have in mind specific floors or ceilings for counts that OK and you want to catch those below the floor or above the ceiling? Or (2) Do you already have in mind % changes from day to day that are too small or to large? Or (3) Do you want a statistical rule to tell you when to worry? All maybe OK, but which?

Comment: Two ideas on things to investigate: (a) industrial 'control charts' of various kinds and the various traditional 'alarm' rules that go with them. (b) boxplot outliers.